# "Package [] does not have a path" when trying to load file with meshes into gazebo

Tags: gazebo, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS kinetic, Ubuntu 14.04

I have followed all the steps in the tutorial to create a catkin workspace and a package, and when i run `rospack find my_package` i get the location to `my_package`. However, when I launch my project i get the error

```
[rospack] "Package [] does not have a path".
```

Also, i can load the same urdf into rviz without a problem.

Here is a snippet from the code:

```
   <link name="base_link">
    <inertial>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <mass value="187"/>
      <inertia ixx="7.9" ixy="-9" ixz="-0.4" iyy="234" iyz="0.03" izz="233"/>
    </inertial>
    <collision>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0.04"/>
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://romovi/src/romovi_dae/corpo_c.dae"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>
    <visual>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://romovi/src/romovi_dae/corpo_v.dae"/>
      </geometry>
    </visual>
  </link>
  <gazebo reference="base_link">
    <kp>1000.0</kp>
    <kd>10.0</kd>
    <mu1>10.0</mu1>
    <mu2>10.0</mu2>
    <material>Gazebo/Red</material>
  </gazebo>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/282928/%22package-%5B%5D-does-not-have-a-path%22-when-trying-to-load-file-with-meshes-into-gazebo/) by [jorgius](https://answers.ros.org/users/33727/jorgius/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2018-02-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Okay, it seems that the setup bash only works for the terminal where you run it, and i was using two different terminals, one for loading the world and the other to load objects into the world.

---

Originally posted by [jorgius](https://answers.ros.org/users/33727/jorgius/) with karma: 16 on 2018-02-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-02-16**:
Any time you open a new terminal you have to `source` your workspace and the `setup.bash` of your ROS distribution. These don't carry over to a new terminal.